# multiple selector to include back $(this)?

Tags: jquery, listitem

I'm not sure is this possible. Selecting multiple element is easy, but today I doubt whether this is possible or not:

```
$(this).closest("li, + $(this)").css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

The above code surely not working. It's just for the demo of the idea. I want to strike the entire `li` (text and the checkbox) so I selected the `li` together with the `checkbox`.

Comment: Even if you fixed the syntax, why would you select an element that's closest to itself? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `line-through` will only apply to text, not a checkbox. You could contrive some custom (and very messy) way to strike through the checkbox but it's more normal (and much simpler) to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).closest("li").andSelf().css('text-decoration','line-through');`

or

`$(this).closest("li").addBack().css('text-decoration','line-through');`

for jQuery 1.8 and above

Comment: Yes, I was just about to say, `.andSelf(`) became deprecated at 1.8 in favour of `.addBack()`.

Comment: So, in this case, the list of objects is the closest li and the original target itself? What an odd set of selected elements but I guess I could see where this might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

[`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$(this).closest("li").add(this).css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is to use [addBack](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), which is dedicated to this usage :

```
$(this).closest("li").addBack().css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't knew this +1

Comment: It should be `addBack()` (JS is case sensitive)

Comment: BTW, why is this the cleanest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function to add selectors:

```
$(this).closest("li").add(this).css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).

> Description: Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the
>   current set.

Code:

```
$(this).closest("li").andSelf().css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

I read now in the docs that:

> Note: This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for
>   .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later.

So use [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) if your are on jQuery 1.8 or later.

Code:

```
$(this).closest("li").addBack().css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your $(this) represents checkbox here. If it's inside li then, you could use

```
$(this).parent('li').css('text-decoration','line-through');
```

This would have cover full li along with checkbox.

```
$(this).closest("li").andSelf().css('text-decoration','line-through');
```